# Oracle APEX loading data into a checkbox list

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a checkbox on my page and I need to load multiple values from the array into the checkbox. How can I do that?

```
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_arr.COUNT
  LOOP
     :P2_CHK1 = v_arr (i)
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: you need to pass a string delimited by colon. I don't know if there is a utility function to do this, but you can concatenated every value in a varchar2 variable and then pass to :P2_CHK1. Example of a valid value: '1:2:4:5'

Comment: thanks! I will give it a shot

Comment: it worked! Could you post your comment as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass a string delimited by colon. I don't know if there is a utility function to do this, but you can concatenated every value in a varchar2 variable and then pass to :P2_CHK1. Example of a valid value: '1:2:4:5'